# memory usage of empty python dictionary in 3.6 vs 3.8

Tags: python

In different versions of python (3.6,3.7,3.8), the same code produces different results.

```
import sys
sys.getsizeof({})
```

In python 3.6, I get 240, in 3.7, I get 248, in 3.8, I get 64; any ideas about what's happening behind the scene?

Comment: Different implementations use memory differently.

Comment: Would you please point me to the details? @Barmar

Comment: I don't know the details, I was just speaking in general. Why would you expect the results to be the same with different implementations? Why does it matter?

Comment: A simple test shows that python3.7 started to optimize zero-sized dict. All these versions take almost the same amount of memory for a 1-element dict.

Comment: Just out of curiosity @Barmar

Comment: From what is said above, I guess here? [v3.8](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/dictobject.c#L699) vs [v3.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/dictobject.c#L672). You can see 3.8 uses shared empty object, but 3.7 is using fresh keys object with space for 8 entries.

Comment: Thank you @Hitobat ! That seems like it